# Why is Pandas insistent on storing times as Pandas Timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have some code which is using `datetime.datetime` format throughout. I have data in `X.csv`:

```
EventDatetime  |  RunnerNumber
"20220203 1024"|  42
"20220203 1331"|  69
  ...          |  ...
```

which I have read into a `pd.dataframe`, with `EventDatetime` as `datetime.datetime` format:

```
dfX = pd.read_csv("X.csv", header=0, 
                  converters={"EventDatetime" : (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")}
                 )
```

(For reference, `datetime.strptime("20220203 1024", "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")` returns a `datetime.datetime` object).

Unfortunately, Pandas seems to convert this format into its native `Timestamp` format, which makes indexing very annoying.

```
dfX.index = dfX["EventDatetime"]
type(dfX.index.iloc[1])  # returns:  pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
dfX.loc[[datetime.datetime(2022,02,03,10,24), datetime.datetime(2022,02,03,13,31)]]
```

*should* return a dataframe with two lines, but rather throws an error because Pandas has converted the `datetime.datetime` object into `timestamp`.

Sadly it seems, Pandas has not kept to the Unix mantra of ``do one thing, and do it well''. I can find ways around this problem (various SO posts have been helpful). But what I want to know is, *Why does Pandas coerce these `datetimes` into `timestamps`?* Is it a bug, or a design feature which I have yet to appreciate?

Comment: If you work with pandas, best use it's [date and time functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html). Not native Python datetime, since that partly follows a different philosophy. And pandas datetime offers extended functionality, like "vectorized" methods for accessing attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the title of your question. But I can index the dateframe with `datetime.datetime` object with the following code

```
import datetime
dfX = pd.DataFrame(
    {'EventDatetime': ['20220203 1024', '20220203 1331'],
     'RunnerNumber': ['42', '69']}
)
dfX['EventDatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfX['EventDatetime'], format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
dfX.index = dfX['EventDatetime']
dfX.loc[[datetime.datetime(2022,2,3,10,24), datetime.datetime(2022,2,3,13,31)]]
```

Output:

```
    RunnerNumber
EventDatetime   
2022-02-03 10:24:00 42
2022-02-03 13:31:00 69
```

I think the key difference is that I used `pd.to_datetime` for the conversion but I don't know the reason behind that difference.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `dfX.loc[[pd.Timestamp("2022-02-03 10:24"), pd.Timestamp("2022-02-03 13:31")]]` to consistently work with pandas datetime.